# How to use IPLib of Intel Imageprocessing Library in vc++?

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, intel-ipp

I have just found IPL21 library of Intel image processing library on web.
But I can't find how to use and compile this library in vc++2010.
There isn't an example about this as I know.
So would you please let me know the example of what how to load and compile the library in vc++2010 and how to read file and use in processing.

Answer (score 0):

IPL library is too outdated to be helpful. It misses code optimizations for all modern CPU architectures. Instead, you better try [community license IPP](https://software.intel.com/sites/campaigns/nest/).Besides optimization it has many additional functions for image processing.